# Calculating mutual Information in absence of a token/string over a class

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, mutual-information

**Equation:**
MI(X,Ci) = ∑P(X,Ci) . log ( P(X,Ci) / P(X)⋅P(Ci) )

where, X is url, t is a url token and Ci is the i-th class will be either spam or ham

**P(t,C)** will be either the frequency that the word "fakedDoamin" appears in all of the spam urls divided by the number of words in the spam urls, or the same for the ham (non-spam) urls.

**P(Xi)** is the probability of the word occurring at all in both spam and ham urls.

The similar problem is discussed in the link: [Calculating mutual Information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19258/calculating-mutual-information?newreg=d6dfe293cbc44163971642cbd422b621)

The only problem which I am facing is that what will be M(X,Ci),
if a token 't' does not exists over a class Ci

i-e P(t,Ci) = P('fakedDoamin', ham) where 'fakedDoamin' does not exists in the ham class.

Therefore, Probability is 0 and Log is undefined. So how should we treat an undefined value?

Comment: One way to look at it is that $\text{log}(0)=-\infty$, and that a mutual information score of negative infinity corresponds to no information. Or assign a prior, allowing you to avoid the zero in the first place

Comment: @BenA Does it means I must skip all such tokens?

Comment: However, According to definition of mutual information this just makes sense to me. 
 
'Mutual information is one of many quantities that measures how much one random variables tells us about another.'