How to compute mutual information between a scalar random variable and a vector random variable?
I have a vector random variable $X = (x_1, x_2... x_n)$ where each $x_i$ has a discrete value. I also have a discrete scalar random variable $Y = y$. Is mutual information between the two defined? If so, how can I compute mutual information between the two? And if not, is there some other metric that is defined for my case, and can be applied similarly to mutual information?

The definition given in the Wikipedia article applies directly.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139368 answers your question for a specific example.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19258 works through another simple example.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32662 explains that approach in general. If you need more, please search our site.

@whuber Unfortunately none of these answer the question. The first of these concerns two scalar random variables, for which the author has counts of each value's occurrence. In the second, the author's data is indeed a vector, but they only want to compute mutual information on each Xi against the target independent of the remaining Xj, which is no different from the case where both are scalars. In the third, the two vectors that the user describes are not vector random variables, but rather, parallel lists of (xi, yi) - again, scalar random variables.

The whole point is that the scalar/vector distinction is immaterial.  Look at the definition again and notice it only involves probabilities: the nature of the random variable is irrelevant.
